# Method group conversions vs. boxing

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion, value-type, method-group

I've created a struct named `Point` and a `List` of such points:

```
var myPoints = new List<Point> {
    new Point() {Col = 3, Row = 2},
    new Point() {Col = 2, Row = 4},
    new Point() {Col = 5, Row = 4},
};
```

When I try to print them using `ForEach()` method, I cannot pass a method group there: `myPoints.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);` gives a compile time error saying that a method with `void WriteLine(Point)` signagure is expected. If I use a lambda expression or change `Point` to be a class instead of struct it works just perfectly.

Why does it happen even though there's always an implicit conversion from any value type to `object` via boxing -- and the method `Console.WriteLine(object)` should therefore be chosen?

Thank you!

Comment: Variance works only on reference types. It is not supported for structs because the conversion requires boxing, which is not representation preserving. This is similar to when you have an function taking a double but you got a list of ints. Even though the compiler will insert an implicit conversion for you, it doesn't mean int is truly like a double to the jitter or the runtime. One is 4 bytes the other 8 bytes.

Comment: @mikez: IMHO, that comment, along with more detail from the C# specification describing the applicable conversion rules, would make a nice answer. :)